# Ubuntu webserver permissions setup for Magento2

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, permissions, magento2

I am struggling with a proper setup of users and permissions on folders for Magento2. Site is installed in `/var/www/html`, web server is Apache operating as `www-data:www-data` on Ubuntu 16.04.

My command line user is `mosadmin`, but it doesn't have read and write permissions on some folders, so I am calling most of the commands using `sudo`.

Everything works fine if I set www-data as owner and group of everything:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data: /var/www/html
```

The problem is, that when I install modules or do some admin tasks, I usually have to call

```
$ sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

When I do this, some folders like some subfolders of  `var/generation` or `var/cache` get `root:root` as owner and Magento cannot write there. This triggers errors and takes the whole site down unless I manually revert everything to www-data again.

Obviously, I want permissions set so, that I don't have to touch them anymore and make sure, that even after calling admin commands the site will stay working. I've tried several things, but none of it worked 100%.

One thing I tried was set the guide bit on some of the folders, which makes sure that newly generated subfolders will inherit parent folder group instead of the group of the user calling the command:

```
$ cd /var/www/html
$ sudo chmod -R g+s pub/static pub/media var/cache var/generation
```

This seems to fix the problem with cache folders being unwritable, but I still get the errors in `var/generation`. The problem here is, that some folders there regenerate with `root:www-data` owners, and because they have permissions `755`, group/apache cannot write there and I am screwed.

I think `umask` is supposed to solve this, but strangely enough when I call `umask`, it gives me `0002`, so that should give write permissions to the group. Still when I do `sudo mkdir test`, it has permissions 755. If I change the umask to something else like `umask 0022`, nothing changes and the permissions still stay the same for new folders.

I am no Linux guru and am slowly running out of ideas. Is there any better way to set this so that I don't have to revert owner of all files after each content regeneration?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww I see, but as it is related to Magento2, it still seem relevant to me. But thanks for the tip, I will move it there if I don't get any answers here

Answer (score -1):

cd

`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

chown -R :

chmod u+x bin/magento`